# NullPointerException with an ArrayList inside of a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am attempting to use an arraylist inside of a hashmap to create and iterate counters for different characters fed to the processLine method. I think I have declared all of the variables and the catch statements should handle the cases in which there isn't an entry in the hashmap, but I am still getting a NullPointerException on the *curCounts.set(i, 1);* line in the second catch statement. I've probably made some dumb mistake, but I can't figure out what it is.

```
HashMap<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> charCounts;

public DigitCount() { charCounts = new HashMap<>(); }


public void processLine (String curLine) {

    int length = curLine.length();
    char curChar;
    ArrayList<Integer> curCounts;
    Integer curCount;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        curChar = curLine.charAt(i);
        try {
            curCounts = charCounts.get(i);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            curCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        try {
            curCount = curCounts.get(i);
            curCount++;
            curCounts.set(i, curCount);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            curCounts.set(i, 1);
        }

        charCounts.put(curChar, curCounts);
    }

    linesProcessed++;
    System.out.println("---------------------------" + linesProcessed);
}
```

Edit: Yes, I did call DigitCount.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    //creates an instance of the digitCount object and starts the run method
    DigitCount counter = new DigitCount();
    counter.run(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: curCounts isn't initialized. Your line of code before the for loop  should be ArrayList<Integer> curCounts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: you can drop the try/catch blocks. Also, you can 'put' and int, I don't think it has to be an Integer.

Comment: `curCounts = charCounts.get(i); if (curCounts==null) {curCounts= new ArrayList<>();charCounts.put(i,curCounts)}` ...

Comment: are you calling your method `DigitCount` before calling `processLine` ?

Comment: I initialized curCounts four lines from the top of the method with ArrayList<Integer> curCounts;

Comment: @user3723352 that's not `initialize`, that's `declare` the variable `curCounts` as an `ArrayList` o type `Integer`. Initialize means, create a new object of that type, i.e. `ArrayList<Integer> curCounts = new ArrayList <Integer>();`

Comment: Have you even tried stepping through the method? Just doing that for a single iteration will be enough to see what the problem is.

Comment: What about using a `List<Integer>` instead of an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if charConts doesn't contain i (as in `charCounts.get(i)`), then it won't throw a NullPointerException, it will return null. Therefore you should be using an if and not a trycatch as in:

```
curCounts = charCounts.get(i);
if(curCounts==null)
    curCounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Edit: Alternatively if you are using java 8 you can do

```
curCounts = charCounts.getOrDefault(i,new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

and it will automatically default to creating a new `ArrayList` if it doesn't contain one